# "Fuzzy" posts tags and posts titles search in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a search function that searches for posts based on their title and the tags the posts has. I wonder if it is possible to do this with just a mysql query or if I need to use 2 queries and then sort the results using php.

The tables I want to query have the following structure:
[image: Table structure]

I've tried doing something like this, but it returns duplicate posts:

```
SELECT post_tags.id, post_tags.tag_id, posts.id, tags.tag_name, 
posts.title
FROM post_tags
JOIN tags ON (tags.tag_name LIKE '%something%' AND post_tags.tag_id = tags.id)
JOIN posts ON (posts.title LIKE '%something%' OR post_tags.post_id = posts.id);
```

I've also heard somewhere that using `LIKE` in mysql is really slow because there is no indexing.

My question is therefore, what is best practice for this case, if there is one?

-- edit --

I added the php code which uses 2 queries to achieve what I want

```
function search($query, $con = null){
    $conn = (isset($con) ? $con : get_conn());
    $logged_in_user_id = current_user.id;

    $posts = Array();
    $param = "%$query%";
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT posts.id, posts.title ...
                                      FROM post_tags
                                      JOIN tags ON  post_tags.tag_id = tags.id
                                      JOIN posts ON  (post_tags.post_id = posts.id OR posts.title LIKE ?)
                                      WHERE posts.title LIKE ? OR tags.tag_name LIKE ?;")){
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $param,$param, $param);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $title ...);
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            if(!array_key_exists($id, $posts)){
                $posts[$id] = new Post($id, $title ...);
            }
        }
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
SELECT  posts.id, posts.title
FROM post_tags
JOIN tags ON  post_tags.tag_id = tags.id
JOIN posts ON  post_tags.post_id = posts.id
WHERE tags.tag_name LIKE '%something%' OR posts.title LIKE '%something%';
```

Comment: This returned all tags for a post. I need just the posts that are matching either on their title or the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) as `tags`,
FROM posts p
JOIN post_tags p1
ON pt.post_id = posts.id
JOIN tags t
ON pt.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE p.title LIKE '%something%' OR t.tag_name LIKE '%something%'
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.title
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but this seemed to not return posts with a title containing the search query.

Comment: I don't see how that could be. Look at the where clause. It matches all records where the title contains 'something' or where one of the tag_names contains 'something'. If either is true, it should include the row from posts.